# Loop though sheet to create JSON key-value pairs for API POST

Tags: json, google-apps-script, post, zendesk-api

I am attempting to write a POST method Google Apps Script a the moment (quite an achievement for someone scratching around trying to learn as he goes) and have managed step one of my goal which is an initial script that works - in that it runs and creates a field in Zendesk providing I 'hard code'/explicitly write the key-value pairs in the script (as shown below).
What I have been trying to do now is loop through the rows in Sheet to get the key-value pairings and POST(?) that for each row/entry thus allowing me to create multiple fields simply by entering the data in a sheet.

I am sure that it's going to be a for loop but i've hit a brick wall trying to actually figure it out and was hoping someone here could help please.

I have my data in a Sheet in columns A:B (attributes are Type and Title) if that makes sense?  I get frustrated that I know just enough to get me going but not quite how to finish it :-(

```
function CreateField2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // data i want to use is here in columns A:B (type, text) - this will be expanded to other attributes eventually
//this is my data explicitly called out which works fine
  var data = {"ticket_field": {
    "type": "text", "title": "Age"}
  };      
//how do i take the values from my sheet and use them here?

  var url = 'https://url.com/api/v2/ticket_fields';
  var user = 'myaddress@somewhere.com/token';
  var pwd = 'myAPItokenHere';
  var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pwd)
      },
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

My data in the sheet will look like this:
[image]

UPDATE: Following comment below regarding objects vs array of objects.  I think what i actually need to do is alter the loop so that it runs the post method for each iteration?  Added the following:

```
    // Can i change the array of objects into separate objects?
const things = [
  data // this is the data gathered using either of the proposed methods
];
const filteredArr = things.reduce((thing, current) => {
  const x = thing.find(item => item.place === current.place);
  if (!x) {
    return thing.concat([current]);
  } else {
    return thing;
  }
}, []);
console.log(filteredArr)
// End of newly added code
//Note:  Not sure this is the right approach, i think i might need to to iterate over and perform the post function for each one?
```

Comment: Thank you both (Mike & Vector).  I managed to incorporate both of your ideas and and almost have it working.
What I didn't realise at the time (and apologies for this)  is that that working version's results are an object {} whereas what i am getting now is an array of objects; reading the Zendesk API documentation a little further and seeking guidance from a colleague it would appear that it is expecting objects rather than array of objects.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your latest problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this :-

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // data i want to use is here in columns A:B (type, text) - this will be expanded to other attributes eventually
//this is my data explicitly called out which works fine
  var data = {"ticket_field": {
    "type": "text", "title": "Age"}
  };
```

With this:-

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const dataRange = ssSource.getDataRange().getValues();    
  var result = [];
  var head = dataRange[0]; // Getting Head Row
  var cols = head.length;
  var row = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < dataRange.length; i++)
  {
    row = dataRange[i]; // Getting data Rows
    var obj = {}; // Clearing Object
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
    {
      obj[head[col]] = row[col];  // Assigning values to Keys  
    }
    result.push(obj);  // Pushing Object
  } 
  const data = JSON.stringify({ "ticket_field" : result}).replace(/[[\]]/g, '')
```

You can remove `JSON.stringify` in option parameter

Reference:

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function table2json() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = {}
  var items = []
  rows.forEach(function(r) {
    var obj={}
    r.forEach(function (c, j) {
      obj[headers[j]] = c
    })
    items.push(obj)
  })
  data['ticket_field'] = items
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

you will get

```
{"ticket_field":[{"type":"text","title":"Summary"},{"type":"Multi-line text","title":"Description"},{"type":"Drop-down list","title":"Choose a thing"}, ... ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both; after a few more hours or deliberation (Googling/trial and error) I have it working with the following code:

```
function CreateFields(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var data = {}
 var items = []
 rows.forEach(function(r) {
   var obj={}
   r.forEach(function (c, j) {
     obj[headers[j]] = c
   })
    var data = {}//moved
   data['ticket_field'] = obj // moved this inside your loop
   items.push(data) // pushed the object into the items array
 })
 
 Logger.log(JSON.stringify(items))
 
 items.forEach(function(i) {   // added this to loop over objects in items
 var url = 'https://urlhere.com/api/v2/ticket_fields';
 var user = 'myemailaddress/token';
 var pwd = 'mytokenhere';
 var options = {
     'method' : 'post',
     'headers': {
       'Authorization': "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pwd)
     },
     'payload' : JSON.stringify(i),
     'contentType': 'application/json',
     'muteHttpExceptions': true
 };
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 Logger.log(i)
})
}
```